# MATLAB putting numbers into matlab from a matrix into a string of characters

Tags: string, matlab, encryption, matrix

Im having trouble with the decryption part(Not really encryption)

```
prompt = 'Enter a sentence you would like to Encrypt';
dlg_title = 'Input';
num_lines = 5;
defaultans = {'Hello'};
answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,defaultans);

answer = answer{1};




% find out how big the square matrix for data should be
for i = 1:length(answer) % it should never run this far anyway
   if (i^2) > length(answer) 
       break;
   end
end

mat_len = i; 

% predefine square matrix of numbers forcing matrixA to number type
matrixA = zeros(mat_len,mat_len); 

% iterate through square matrix assigning answer values to positions
for i = 1:mat_len
    for j = 1:mat_len
        if (((i-1)*mat_len)+j) <= length(answer)
         matrixA(i,j) = answer(((i-1)*mat_len)+j);
        else
            break;
        end
    end
end
matrixA(1)=matrixA(1)*10
matrixA'
```

My issue is that I don't know how to get the matrix back to a string. Like for instance

```
   720   108     0
   101   111     0
   108     0     0
```

When input back into the code should be "Hello", but I don't know what to do or how to even start the decryption part, how would I input the ASCII codes back into matlab and get the string?

Comment: Well, you can start by doing `char(matrixA)`, but it is unclear what you hope to achieve.

Comment: Was the first entry in that matrix supposed to be `72` instead of `720`? Because `720` isn't an ASCII code.

Comment: Yeah the matrix is modified to hide the real value

Comment: Oh, well. Carry on, then.

Comment: When I do char(matrixA) it turns into

Comment: Hel;lo , the lo is on a separate line

Comment: matrixA''
    matrixA(1)=matrixA(1)/10
    m2=matrixA.'; char(m2(:)).';
    char(matrixA)

Comment: It still is outputting the same thing

Comment: My mistake. :) `m2=matrixA.'; result=char(m2(:)).';` Now, `result` should have your string.

Comment: @beaker Have a nice day!