# MATLAB Code not working. Trying to store input into an array

Tags: matlab

I wrote two functions, first one is to Encrypt

```
prompt = 'Enter a sentence you would like to Encrypt';
dlg_title = 'Input';
num_lines = 5;
defaultans = {'Hello'};
answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,defaultans);

answer = answer{1};




% find out how big the square matrix for data should be
for i = 1:length(answer) % it should never run this far anyway
   if (i^2) > length(answer) 
       break;
   end
end

mat_len = i; 

% predefine square matrix of numbers forcing matrixA to number type
matrixA = zeros(mat_len,mat_len); 

% iterate through square matrix assigning answer values to positions
for i = 1:mat_len
    for j = 1:mat_len
        if (((i-1)*mat_len)+j) <= length(answer)
         matrixA(i,j) = answer(((i-1)*mat_len)+j);
        else
            break;
        end
    end
end
matrixA(1)=matrixA(1)*10
matrixA'
```

This stores the ASCII code into the array matrixA and does simple matrix operations to hide the message.
For instance Hello would be

```
   720   108     0
   101   111     0
   108     0     0
```

The second function is where my problem is, it is spossed to take the input of the matrix and convert it back to the message. 720 turns into 72 which is H. The function instead reads from matrixA which is already stored.

```
prompt = 'Enter a code you would like to Decrypt';
dlg_title = 'Input';
num_lines = 5;
defaultans = {''};
answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,defaultans);

answer = answer{1};



for i = 1:length(answer) % it should never run this far anyway
   if (i^2) > length(answer) 
       break;
   end
end

mat_len = i; 

% predefine square matrix of numbers forcing matrixA to number type
matrixA = zeros(mat_len,mat_len); 

% iterate through square matrix assigning answer values to positions
for i = 1:mat_len
    for j = 1:mat_len
        if (((i-1)*mat_len)+j) <= length(answer)
         matrixA(i,j) = answer(((i-1)*mat_len)+j);
        else
            break;
        end
    end
end





matrixA''
matrixA(1)=matrixA(1)/10
m2=matrixA.'; result=char(m2(:)).'; 
result
```

This is the code that does not work. How can I get it to read a matrix of numbers and convert them back to characters.

Comment: Maybe your classmate knows? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701484/matlab-putting-numbers-into-matlab-from-a-matrix-into-a-string-of-characters

Comment: That's me, I lost the password to that account, and the code isnt working like I thought it was. It was reading the matrixA from the first function when I tested it but if you do clear all and run the second function then It does not work at all

Comment: How do I get the user input go directly into matrixA in the second function?

Comment: First of all these aren't functions they are [scripts](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/scripts-and-functions.html) so it may be that your second script depends upon variables that are defined in the first script. If this is the case, then you need to figure out what they are and defined them.

Comment: Alright, I know where they are defined. For instance, if I get the code for Hello and run the first function then I run it again this time with HelloA, Even if I put in the numbers for Hello, it will still say the result is HelloA

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with my code, it should not be doing that.

Comment: Well one issue is that you've dividing matrixA(1) by 10. This causes the ASCII code to be a non-printable character which is why you don't see it.

Comment: I get two different answers depending on what I put in for the first part so I can't reproduce that issue

Comment: So should I put that before the for loops then?

Comment: Right, if I put the numbers for something other than what I inputed in the first script into the second script it still outputs the first scripts letters

Comment: No. You should come up with an ecryption/decryption scheme that actually produces valid output. You had the /10 in there because your encryption scheme on 'Hello' made the first element of the matrix equal to 720 which isn't a valid ASCII code. But by dividing by 10, now when you try to decrypt the message it fails because you're dividing by 10 again (rather than multiply to "undo" it) and you get an output different than expected. Also the /10 is *specific* to your input so if I change the string into "elloH" instead, your algorithm will completely fail.

Comment: How should I fix it then? What should I change with my code to fix it?

Comment: That seems like the point of the assignment. You're not going to learn anything if someone just gives you a functional encryption scheme...

Comment: Its not an assignment... Its a project where we have to build our own thing and I did I just need some help